# Not able to add event listener to HTML element

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

Not able to add event listener to span element. Please help. Please let me know if it is possible to debug this.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="test">Click me!</span>
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById('test');
        element.addEventListener('onclick', function ()
        {
            alert('it works!')
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Replace `"onclick'` by `"click"`. You need to add the `"on"` prefix when you do something like `domElement.onclick = function () {...}`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @Seblor, it is working now. when is onclick used here

Comment: You can add a listener using the `onclick` property, but this will override any that has already been set before. It's a better practice to use `addEventListener("click", ...)`

Comment: @Seblor, thank you... i was reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick and didn't notice spelling difference there  :(

Comment: @Seblor is it possible to debug this in developer tools, that we are not adding proper event name

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. No you cannot check (or fire an exception) if you added the event handler to the correct event, since you can create and fire custom events that can be named arbitrarily.

Comment: @Seblor, so, i think even IDE or linters won't detect this mistakes by what you say.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment :

You need to replace "onclick' by "click".

The "on" prefix is used when you do add the function as the property like `domElement.onclick = function () {...}`

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    alert('it works!')
})
```

```html
<span id="test">Click me!</span>
```